# Is std::ref really necessary when passing references to threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stdthread

I'm reading through C++ Concurrency in Action and in Chapter 2 I'm led to believe that even if a function prototype, e.g:

```
void MagicFunc(Data& myData);
```

is intended to be used like the following:

```
Data dataExample;
thread t(MagicFunc,dataExample);
```

I should really do this

```
Data dataExample
thread t(MagicFunc,std::ref(dataExample));
```

or otherwise the changes I expect to have happened to "dataExample" won't have take place. Specifically it states something like:

> Although MagicFunc expects the second parameter to be passed by
>   reference, the std::thread constructor t doesn’t know that; it’s
>   oblivious to the types of the arguments expected by the function and
>   blindly copies the supplied values. When it calls Magicfunc, it will
>   end up passing a reference to the internal copy of data and not a
>   reference to data itself. Consequently, when the thread finishes,
>   these updates will be discarded as the internal copies of the supplied
>   arguments are destroyed, and process_widget_data will be passed an
>   unchanged Data myData rather than a correctly updated version.

However, testing this out with the following program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <assert.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

const int NUM_VALS = 50000000;

#define _MULTICORE 

void AddValuesToSlots(vector<int>& vecVals,vector<int>::iterator& begin,
                      int num,int startNum){
    int i = startNum;
    auto end = begin + num;
    for (auto itr = begin; itr < end; ++itr){
        *itr = i++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> vecVals;
    vecVals.resize(NUM_VALS);

    //get number of cores and divide up the workload
    unsigned int numCores = thread::hardware_concurrency();
    unsigned int slotsPerThread = NUM_VALS / numCores;

    //for timing
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();


    thread* t = new thread[numCores];

    //get the iterator to the beginning
    auto begin = vecVals.begin();

#ifdef _MULTICORE
    for (int core = 0; core < numCores; ++core){
        t[core] = thread(AddValuesToSlots, vecVals, begin + core*slotsPerThread,
            slotsPerThread, core*slotsPerThread);
    }

    for (int core = 0; core < numCores; ++core){
        t[core].join();
    }
#else
    AddValuesToSlots(vecVals, begin, NUM_VALS, 0);
#endif


    delete[] t;

    //how long did it take?
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    cout << duration_cast<milliseconds>(t2-t1).count() << endl;

#ifdef _DEBUG
    //test that the values are correct
    for (int slot = 0; slot < NUM_VALS; ++slot)
        assert(vecVals[slot] == slot);
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

I've tried encasing `vecVals` in a `std::ref` and without, both times it executes without problem. Is the `std::ref` then really necessary and the information provided erroneous?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please remove all the irrelevant code (most of what you posted) and post an MCVE?

Comment: It's unusual to pass iterators by reference like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not altering vecVals directly. Iterators are working because copying iterators is ok, it still points to the same memory address

Comment: It seems so obvious now. Brilliant. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The code you posted is actually illegal under the standard.  `std::thread` should be calling `AddValuesToSlots` with rvalue copies of your arguments.

Some C++ compilers get this wrong, and instead call it with lvalue copies of your arguments.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3482deb21bf23637)

An easy way to test if your compiler is breaking the rules is:

```
void func1(int&&) { std::cout << "func1\n"; }
void func2(int&) { std::cout << "func1\n"; }

int main() {
  int x;
  std::thread t1(func1, x);
  t1.join();
  std::thread t2(func2, x);
  t2.join();
}
```

if `t1` ctor is accepted and `t2` rejected, your compiler is compliant.

If `t2` ctor is accepted and `t1` rejected, your compiler has a violation of the standard.

[See here for more about this MSVC compiler bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28330984/1774667)

Comment: t2 is accepted and t1 is in fact rejected:

Error 1 error C2664: 'void (int &&)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'int &&' 

So it looks like Visual Studio is guilty on both counts - for my "illegal" code and also for the example you posted. Are you really sure?

Comment: @LloydCrawley both are rejected?  That is surprising!  What compiler and version and flags?

Comment: Sorry, I submitted too early by accident, edited ^

BTW Visual Studio Community 2013 vers. 12.0.31101.00 update 4

Comment: @LloydCrawley I knew MSVC got it backwards: I was surprised that there was a compiler that rejected *both*!  The `std` C++11 library in MSVC has a number of such issues, and as it is (as far as I know) closed source, they are harder to fix than in open source libraries.  It is a subtle quirk in the implementation: basically because you are only going to call the function *once*, moving the contents of your stored pack of arguments into the call is the right thing to do (and, as a bonus, demanded by the standard).  The demand is a bit obtuse, I will admit.

Comment: @LloydCrawley http://stackoverflow.com/a/28330984/1774667 for more discussion of this bug